# Ruby Integer and Fixnum unexpexted behavior

Tags: ruby, integer, fixnum

I want to use gcd function of the Integer class. Using the example from [Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.html#M001158) as a test it fails:

```
irb(main):001:0> 72.gcd 168
NoMethodError: undefined method `gcd' for 72:Fixnum
        from (irb):1
```

I have the windows one click installer `ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]`. On other PCs with the same version of ruby this works correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps some gem messed up your `Fixnum` class? Check whether you have some gem installed on the first machine, and not on the other.

Comment: Yes, quite a lot of extra gems on the problem machine

Comment: @Gerhard Teachable moment: And that's why one should always use gemsets or bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
require 'rubygems'
72.gcd 168
```

Answer (score 2):

`require 'rational'`